# How do I replace glassfish default libraries with newer libs?

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, guava

I am trying to deploy my Spring MVC application to Glassfish 4. I am receiving an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList
```

which appears because by default Glassfish 4 uses old guava lib. What I've tried to do:

1) I included newer guava jar into my dependencies, but this did not help

2) I copied newer guava jar into glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ex, but this did not help as well.

The only solution that helped was to copy new guava lib into glassfish4/glassfish/modules, and the application deployed successfully.

But I don't like this solution, because it is a kind of dirty hack to replace libs on the server level. This may cause conflicts with other apps.

And ideas, how to do it in other way?

Comment: Guava is an older version in GlassFish due to a dependency from (I think) Weld. You could try to deploy your application to the latest release of Payara Server which has a newer Guava or use the Payara property to disable Classloader delegation (i.e. prefer libs packaged in your WAR to libs from the server) 
https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html